# Metric spaces proof triangle inequality

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing, metric-spaces

I need to prove the triangle inequality using $d(x, y) = |x_2 − x_1| +|y_2 − y_1|$. I started using $x, y,$ and $z$ as variables.

$|x-y|\leq |x-z|+|z-y|$. I don't know how to prove it from here. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is this even a metric?

Answer (score 1):

First let's prove the simpler version of the triangle inequality.
$|a+b| \le |a| + |b| \iff$
$(|a+b|)^2 \le (|a|+|b|)^2\\
a^2 + 2ab + b^2 \le a^2 + 2|ab| + b^2\\
ab \le |ab|$

This is true as the two sides are equal when $a,b$ have the same sign and the left-hand side is negative while the right-hand side is positive when they have opposite signs.

Now substitute $a = x-z$ and $b = z-y$